# How to set dynamic properties whose values are statements

Tags: soapui

I have defined two dynamic properties at test suite level: "EffectiveDate" and "ExpirationDate" which are used in the request to be tested.

[image]

Then I am trying to test them with a Groovy script to check which values are generated but the values obtained is the expression unresolved not the dates.

[image]

What I am missing here? Can I set this type of statements as value for properties?

I have tried successfully to execute this expressions in a groovy script directly and the statements are working fine.

[image]

**Soap UI version:** 5.5.0

Thanks.

Comment: re Custom Properties.  As you know, they have a key and value.  Both of these are strings, which may explain why you're not getting the desired result.  It might be worth casting to a string ( or a dateVar.toString() call) before you write them.

Comment: @ChrisAdams thank you for you answer. I have tried the casting but the same result. Finally I have resolved it by defining the two variables in the "Setup Script" tab and loading them in the "testSuite" variable for later use in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are retrieving it now, you get the pure string value.
If you want SoapUI to execute the code, and then return the result of that, you may use context.expand

```
log.info context.expand( '${#TestSuite#EffectiveDate}' )
```